# Correctly reading this $\lim \inf ()$ and $\lim \sup()$ expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I've never thought that I would have difficulties to read such a simple formula, which goes as follows<sup>1</sup>:

> A well-known unsolved problem in number theory concerns the distribution of $(3/2)^n\pmod1$. The sequence is believed to be uniformly distributed, which is the case for almost all real numbers $\theta^n\pmod1$, but it is not even known to be dense in $[0,1]$. One of the few positive results known for (non-integer) rational $\theta=p/q$ is that of Vijayaraghavan ($1940$), who showed that the set $(p/q)^n\pmod1$ has infinitely many limit points. Vijayaraghavan later remarked that it was striking that one could not even decide whether or not $(3/2)^n\pmod1$ has infinitely limit points in $[0,1/2)$ or in $[1/2,1)$. Both these latter assertions would follow if one could show that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left(\frac32\right)^n\right\}-\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left(\frac32\right)^n\right\}>\frac12.$$

I assume surely correctly, that the curly braces mean the fractional part. And $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup()$ the highest occuring fractional value (or better its limit) and the other the lowest occuring fractional value (or better its limit) . But of course already for small $n$ the left expression approaches $1$ and the right expression approaches $0$, which makes its difference larger than $1/2$.

So obviously I must misread something elementary. Just trying to remove the tomato from my eyes...

<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi1lN.png)</sup> Flatto, Lagarias, 1995 "On the range of fractional parts { ξ(p/q) n }"

Comment: The whole point of that paragraph is to point out that while it is widely believed that $\{(3/2)^n\}$ approaches both $1$ and $0$ as $n$ grows, we simply _do not know_. Maybe all terms are larger than $\frac12$ from some point on. We have no idea.

Comment: @MartinR : I always understood the $\lim \inf()$ means the "global" minimum. But it seems I've never got that correctly...?

Comment: No, $\liminf_{n\to \infty}$ and $\limsup_{n\to \infty}$ means the _eventual_ min / max (or, rather, inf and sup instead of min and max). They are what the (global) $\inf$ and $\sup$ converge to as you successively delete entries from the _beginning_ of the sequence.

Comment: @Arthur - ah, that last half-sentence seems to shed light into my brain... I guess I'll get it slowly...

Comment: @Arthur - please make an answer from your comment that I can "accept" it and can "close the case".

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 - I think this is grossly overcriticism: the screenshot presented here was *easily readable* and was *not a page scan* (which is *forbidden in SE-network*). Being insure whether oneself might have a simple but big misunderstanding of some read text it seems to me more sanely to simply show what oneself has had before his eyes and not what comes after (likely) misreading and translation. But well - if we have such harsh reaction on MSE I think I better retract the image (I should not simply delete the question according to the system-advice when trying to self-delete)

Comment: I've asked at META https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30184/1714 what to do with this question.

Comment: I begin my last message with *please*, and I've included links to related [meta] discussions so that you can know more about that.  I don't see any harshness in my previous comments.  What I'm politely asking for is to [be nice](//math.stackexchange.com/conduct) to others, including the visually impaired, those with disorders in reading and writing, searching engines, etc.  They *can't see* images, but they can *hear from screen readers*.  The main point is that images *aren't* SEO friendly, that is, they *can't* be *searched*.  They might hinder future users from finding this post

Comment: and its great answer.  By saying *page scan*, that's just a common example of *text images*, that is, images files whose content is actually text.  The arguments still applies here, no matter it's a scan or not.  Thanks for raising this on [meta].  I'll take the time to further explain this.

Comment: As T Bongers points out, I've *misused* the word "forbidden", and I apologize for that.  I should have said "*discouraged* since there's *no* explicit mechanism that stops the upload of text images.

Comment: @TheSimplifire - many thanks for your help in conversion of the scan! For me it was just some "2-minutes-question" - too little to think about big things. A simple "please would you mind to convert that scan into text" could have made me coming to back to this later and do it myself. My head is deeply involved to understand one more difficult article of Lagarias around this subject so not much space for more. So I feel warm you did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a sequence $a_n$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is an *eventual* supremum, not a global supremum of $a_n$. What I mean by that is that it doesn't care about what the early terms do, only what happens as $n\to \infty$.

Slightly more rigorously, if you successively delete entries from the beginning of the sequence $a_n$ (i.e. start at $n = 2$ instead of $n = 1$, then start at $n = 3$ instead of $n = 2$, and so on), then the (global) $\sup a_n$ might stay the same, or it might decrease. Whatever it converges to (be it a real number or $-\infty$), *that* is $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n$

Example:
$$
a_n = \frac 1n + (-1)^n\\
\begin{array}{|c|cccccc}
\hline n & 1&2&3&4&5&\cdots\\
\hline a_n&0&\frac32&-\frac23&\frac54&-\frac45&\cdots\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
The largest term in this sequence is $\frac32$, for $n = 2$. So $\sup a_n = \frac32$. However, if we delete the first two terms, then the new largest term is $\frac 54$ for $n = 4$. And so on. The largest term of whatever is left keeps shrinking as we keep deleting terms, and it converges to $1$.

$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$ works the same way, only with $\inf$. Using the example above again, we see that there is no smallest term. But there is a (global) $\inf a_n = -1$. This will stay exactly where it is as we delete terms, as it is the tail end of the sequence which gives it this $\inf$. So $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n = -1$.

And be careful labeling $\inf$ and $\sup$ (and their $\lim$ variations) as "min" and "max". It is not the same (although they fill much of the same role). The sequence $a_n$ doesn't *have* a min, as it never becomes $-1$, but comes ever closer to it, so the $\inf$ is $-1$.

Going back to your original sequence, the whole point of that paragraph is to point out that while it is widely suspected that $\{(3/2)^n\}$ approaches both $1$ and $0$ as $n$ grows, we simply do not know. Maybe all terms are larger than $\frac12$ from some point on. An in that case, the $\liminf$ would be $\frac12$, or even larger.

Comment: Many thanks for that thorough explanations! Funny, I have certain difficulties to grasp this firmly. Seems I've to do some exercises with more good examples to get familiar with it.

Comment: Hmm,what about the fractional part of $ \{N \cdot \beta \}$ *(where $\beta= \log_2(3)$)* ? This is oscillating between $0$ and $1$ as well, and we know, that at such $N$ indicated by the convergents of the continued fraction of $ \beta$ we get ever more extreme examples approaching $0$ or $1$ with increase of $N$ (but of course no actual convergence to some limit). Is this cont-frac-effect enough for having a $\lim \sup()$ / $\lim \inf()$ ?

Comment: I've now looked at the wikipedia (german) from where I thought I remember some short explanation a couple of years ago. Now it has excellent explanation and illustration such that I think the question in my previous comment is to be answered in the positive. (Or not?)

Answer (score 1):

" But of course already for small n the left expression approaches 1 and the right expression aproaches 0, which makes its difference larger than 1/2."

But we care aobut BIG n!

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

There is not always a relationship between $\lim \sup$/$\lim \inf$ and global maximums/minimums. You may want to think about it in the following way:

For very big $n$ (meaning, as big of $n$ as we arbitrarely decide to choose), our sequence/function will be oscilating in some range, with its lower boundary being $\lim \inf$ and its upper boundary being $\lim \sup$ Higher values than the $\lim \sup$ may be achieved for smaller $n$

As an example for that, let $f(x):=\frac{1}{x}$ for every $x>=1$ We have a global maximum point at $x=1$ with $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ (when $n \to \infty$) being both 0

Comment: Possibly the problem of my understanding is that I assume $\lim \sup()$ and $\lim \inf()$ as somehow global maximum/minimum , but which cannot be less extreme as some local maximum/minimum... Can you take on this likely problem of mine?

Comment: I editted the question to provide some info about $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$

Comment: Hmm, thanks also for your extended answer. I must confess there is some subtlelety that I've missed completetely when I've met that concept first time and have read just over it (surely asked wikipedia once...). I'll need some more time for chewing this with more examples - thanks again!

Comment: Just looked again into wikipedia, that article (in german) has much very nice explanation this days... I think that shall suffice for all my needs!