# Is $\ \left\{\ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\mod 1:\quad n \in \mathbb{N}\ \right\}\ $ a dense subset of $\ [0,1]\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Is $\ \left\{\ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\mod 1:\quad n \in \mathbb{N}\ \right\}\ $ a dense subset of $\ [0,1]\ $ ?

I know how to prove that if $\ \gamma\ $ is irrational, then sets like $\ \left\{\ \gamma\ n\mod 1:\quad n \in \mathbb{N}\ \right\}\ $ is a dense subset of $\ [0,1].\ $ But my question above seems unrelated to this, I think.

I've got a feeling the answer is yes, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

This question arose when thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215964/does-there-exist-n-m-in-mathbbn-such-that-lvert-left-frac32-ri) I asked a few days ago.

Comment: This is an [open problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3208219/471884).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: "Well-known open problem" is a reason to close.

Comment: It is? I don't see why if there isn't a good dupe target.

Comment: My lecture in Ergodic Theory mentioned in lectures that this is not known.